# Oracle DB user cannot see data in its own view

Tags: database, oracle, view, privileges

There is a user in my Oracle 12c database that has several views created from selecting columns from another user's tables. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "MYSER"."VIEW1" (column1, column2, column3) 
  AS SELECT (column1, column2, column3)
     FROM OTHERSCHEMA.TABLENAME;
```

Now when running

```
select count(1) from MYSER.VIEW1
```

as sys user, I can see all the rows are there. However, as soon as I log into MYSER schema, and try to run the same select count statement, I either get a lower number or rows than the total, or no rows at all. (when doing this for several of the views done in the same fashion)

I have granted select on all of *OTHERUSER's* tables to *MYUSER*

This data was imported from another database. Not sure if that is what could be causing the issues.

EDIT: I have also tried granting

```
Grant execute on DBMS_RLS to MYUSER;
```

Thinking that it could be an issue with the partitions in the table. It could be something funky that the people that coded this application years ago enabled that I need to find out where they security levels or something in place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A view is just a stored SQL statement.
When connected as myser

```
select * from view1;
```

should return exactly the same as

```
select column1, column2, column3 FROM OTHERSCHEMA.TABLENAME;
```

Comment: As this is correct, in either way that you have stated, (which I have tried both ways) it still only displays either 0 rows, or not the whole amount. There is no where clause so it should display ALL rows.